# Convert part of string to JSON for DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, leaflet

I'm working with DataTables and Leaflet and want to show the data seen below on my screen with Datatables. I want to convert it to JSON minus the {....} part. How do I do this?

```
1, 9.12345678912345, 22.123456789132345, AAAAAAA, XXX, {"type":"Point","coordinates":[6.557876,53.456783]}, ;
2, 6.12345678912345, 41.216375999999997, BBBBBBB, YYY, {"type":"Point","coordinates":[6.531819,53.216376]}, ;
3, 4.12345678912345, 90.213718123465500, CCCCCCC, ZZZ, {"type":"Point","coordinates":[6.510978,53.213718]}, ;
```

Comment: What about a condition that excludes object types from your output?

Comment: What do you expect the data to look like in JSON? The `{...}` part is the only part of this that is JSON at the moment. If these lines are just strings, can you just use a regex to match all of the line up to the `{` character?

Comment: I'm pretty new to JSON etc., but i think it should look somehing like`var test = [
 {"id": 1, "x": 9.12345678912345, "y": 22.123456789132345, "brand": "AAAAAAA", "name": "XXX"},.........
];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much more simple solution for my (bigger underlying) problem. I've used the following code to run through my GeoJSON array and return the data I needed.

`geojson.features.map(function(row) { return row.properties; })`